# Listener for Done button on EditText and clear EditText when user not press Done button?

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

I have an EditText and I want to listen for if the user presses the "done" button on the keypad and I also want to clear EditText when user not presses the "done" button on the softkeypad , how would I do this?

Comment: What do you mean with "when user not presses the done button", in which scenario do you want to clear th EditText?

Comment: @cherif : YES , I want to clear the EditText.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To check user pressed "Done" button of soft keyboard, use the code below:

```
edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        if(i== EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Done pressed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

To clear the text of edittext once focus has been changed, use the code below:

```
edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus){
            edittext.setText("");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: sometime user want to give up edittext context and close softkeypad without save.

Comment: I have updated my code. Please look once. If it resolves your issue, please mark it as an answer to get correct answer for others too.

Comment: which one is on first?
Because I put setOnFocusChangeListener in first , the setOnEditorActionListener is second . 
when i input Edittext then press done button ,

Comment: Sequence doesn't matter. SetOnFocusChangeListener will get call once you focused on edittext or you removed the focus from edittext.  setOnEditorActionListener will get call once soft keyboard will get opened. Can you check please whether it satisfying your cases or not.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin like so:

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"

edittext.onFocusChangeListener = OnFocusChangeListener { view, hasFocus ->
                if (hasFocus) {
                    //Logic Here
                }
            }
```